# JNLP/Webstart - Setting environment variables

Tags: java, jnlp, aspectj

Is there a way via the jnlp file, to set up an environmental variable? I want to set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in order to do some LTW with aspectj.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when with the JNLP you have access to JVM environment variables, as per my answer?

Comment: Not really an answer, but an addition:
Here is the relevant bug to vote on for enabling load-time weaving webstart applications: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6356496

Answer (score 3):

In the resources section of the JNLP you can add any number of `property` nodes after your jars. These then become equivalent to a -D option on the command line.

```
<resources>
    <j2se...
    <jar href="...

    <property name="env0" value="value0"/>
    <property name="env1" value="value1"/>
    <property name="env2" value="value2"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that helps. In my testing this has no effect setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS as a property. Is actually setting a property supposed to be equivalent to an environmental variable? The reason I want to set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is to define a new javaagent for Load Time Weaving.

Comment: A property is not an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is going to be to set the variable on the client side before running java web start.

There are ways to pass parameters to the JVM, if there's a JVM parameter that will do what you want -- I'm not sure what JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS does.

Comment: The problem with that is that it negates the use of webstart. At this stage it looks like we'll have to use compile time weaving instead of load time, that is all

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Java Control Panel and in the Java tab select View. In the Runtime Parameters field for the given JRE add:

```
-javaagent=c:\MyAgent.jar
```

providing your agent is in the MyAgent.jar file.

Depending on your agent code output should appear in the Java Console.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there appears to be no way to set the javaagent via webstart. This prevents us using load time weaving with a webstart application. We'll revert to compile time weaving for now.